# Testing scrollintoview Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a simple function:

```
scrollToSecondPart() {
    this.nextPartRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

and I would like to test it using Jest. When I call my function I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null
```

The code works great in the application but not in the unit test.
Here is the unit test:

```
    it("should scroll to the second block", () => {

    const scrollToSecondPart = jest.spyOn(LandingPage.prototype, 'scrollToSecondPart');
    const wrapper = shallow(<LandingPage />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.scrollToSecondPart();

    expect(scrollToSecondPart).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I guess the problem is that the unit test can't access to `this.nextPartRef` but I don't know how I should mock this element.
By the way, I'm using "Refs" has described in https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html (I'm using `React.createRef()`).

Thank you!

Comment: Mocking the element is one strategy. Another strategy could be to make the code more robust e.g. `if(this.nextPartRef.current){this.nextPartRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });}`. Your test is about whether the method has been called. If the test was about whether the scroll has happened, then mocking the element is probably needed.

Comment: @Kunukn thanks for your help. Your solution is working. I understand your point but if someone can explain how to mock this, it would be nice. Right know, I don't need to test that the scroll happened, but maybe one day I would need to :) Thank you !

Answer (score 43):

So I stumbled on this question because I thought it was about how to test [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), which can be done by mocking it with jest as follows:

```
let scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();
window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock;

<execute application code that triggers scrollIntoView>

expect(scrollIntoViewMock).toBeCalled();
```

However, that does not seem to be your goal. In your test you are calling `scrollToSecondPart()` in your test and then `expect(scrollToSecondPart).toHaveBeenCalled()` which is essentially testing that `scrollToSecondPart` is a function of `LandingPage` or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, you're right, `scrollToSecondPart` is a function from `LandingPage`. In this function I do some stuff and at the end I call `scrollInToView`. I would like to test  my function `scrollToSecondPart` but the unit test doesn't work because of the error I've shown in my original post. It looks like what you did may resolve my problem, I'll try your solution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi @Developer Davo, I've tried what you suggested but it doesn't work. I'm still having the same issue. I guess the problem is that I have to mock the ref to the anchor but I don't know how to that. Anyway, thanks for the help !

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @NicolasOuldBouamama Have you solved this?

Comment: @Dejan, sorry for the late reply. I never managed to solve that

Comment: Doesn't test which DOM element was scroll-to,. which is an important aspect of testing such logic. Just testing if the method was called, in general, doesn't say much for most testing scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

for me i had to mock the scrollIntoView for elements like this:

```
const scrollIntoViewMock = jest.fn();

Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = scrollIntoViewMock()
```

as found here:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1695#issuecomment-449931788