# how to use `scollIntoView` method in jest framework automation

Tags: javascript, jestjs, scrollview

I am using the `scroolIntoView` to scroll the window for a particular view is visible but is shown the error like

> 'scrollIntoView' is not a function.

Anyone explain how to use this method in jest + javascript framework.

Comment: Think you need to mock it as jest doesn't run with an actual DOM.

this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527362/testing-scrollintoview-jest

Comment: Please add the code which you want to test.